# The camera does not ignore the light source?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I gave the light source a layer, removed this layer from the camera, but she continues to see it, although if you do the same with a 3D object (a cube, for example), then everything works
How can I make the camera ignore the light source?
[image]

Comment: Read more carefully, the question of why the camera continues to see light

Comment: I did. Now you have changed it. Sure it has question

Comment: via the layers you decide which **objects** you render or not .. the lights are calculated in a different level so the objects will already have received the light before your camera renders

Answer (score 0):

```
[SerializeField] private Light limelight;

private void OnPreCull()
{
    limelight.enabled = false;
}
private void OnPreRender()
{
    limelight.enabled = false;
}
private void OnPostRender()
{
    limelight.enabled = true;
}
```

add this code to the camera that should not see the light and everything will work